# Назначить значение переменной через настройки

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Как присваивать значение переменной через настройки?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно использовать [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Вот еще один [урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html) по этому вопросу. [Офф документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?hl=ru) по Android Settings (на русском).
Суть состоит в том, что нужно получать значение из настроек, где это необходимо.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean yourVariable = sp.getBoolean("yourKey", false);
Log.i(TAG2, "" + yourVariable);
```